# Monitoring Memory and Processor usage on a specific process in Windows?

Tags: windows, performance

We have a tool that's provided to us from a 3rd party vendor, so I don't have source code.  It's basically a scripting execution engine for telecoms hardware that uses (*Sigh*) TCL as it's language.  I want ways see what effect using different coding models have on processor performance and memory utilization.  We are in the process of rewritting the lion's share of our scripting, I want to be able to pull out metrics to see if we are improving or moving the wrong way.

My goals are to reduce code size, memory usuage, and processor usage.

Comment: If it's the Tcl code you need to speed up, you might find some of the tips on the [Tcl Performance wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/348) useful.

Comment: The main concern is parallelism on the server, and system stability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Process Explorer from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals).  There is some pain involved in getting the info programatically.

Windows perfmon will also work but it's a pain in the arse to get some info.

There is also some advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639277/is-there-a-way-to-see-how-much-cpu-usage-per-core-a-process-is-using).